# CSS file is not getting mapped/loaded in SPRING MVC program in eclipse

Tags: java, css, spring, eclipse, model-view-controller

I'm very new to Spring mvc,for this question i've found many answers here but nothing is working for me and please help me to find out what mistake i'm doing here.
I have created a css file under **WebContent>WEB-INF>resources>css>style.css** and mapping is done under spring-servelet.xml and the code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests by efficiently serving up static resources 
         in the corresponding directory -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>

</beans:beans>
```

and i've called the css file from jsp and the jsp file is

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>welcome</title>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="<spring:url value='resources/css/style.css' />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

    <P>The time on the server is ${serverTime}.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Now network is aborted error is displaying at console .As i told i'm newbie to this framework so please help me out other than giving a link to an answer because i've tried almost all.Thank you

Comment: have you tried   `/css/style.css`  (a slash before)? If that you have tried click cntrl+U for view source and click on the css link . Is it loading?

Comment: yes bro, its not yet loaded the css and when i clicked on the link from page source its showing like this,<spring:url%20value='/css/style.css'%20/>

Comment: If still you are unable to resolve this issue trying giving th path directly instead of using spring:url tag `<link href="/css/style.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />

Comment: i have tried that,but its not working...dude I will update my question with complete code please have a look ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `CSS` folder inside `webcontent` and add below code servlet xml file

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

Now you will be able to take the CSS from JSP inside `views` folder using below code -

```
<link href="/css/yourCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

This should work otherwise let usknow!

Comment: not yet solved,the error which is showing at console while inspecting is GET http://localhost:8080/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED  ,is that path correct?

Comment: This doesn't have your project name like  localhost:8080/myproject/css/style.css or have you deployed as ROOT ?

Comment: Dude we did it now its loading the css file,i have updated the reference from jsp as <link href="<spring:url value='/css/style.css' />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />, update your answer .

Comment: @SumithChalil Happy to know that :) go ahead

Answer (score 0):

So, you will need to do what *vipin cp* is suggesting. You need this:

```
<link href="<spring:url value='/css/style.css' />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

This is because the you are using the mapping  `mapping="/css/**"` , so your value needs to begin with the same thing as your mapping `"/css/..."`, without the beginning slash, it doesn't match your mapping so spring doesn't know where to map it too, you could also change your mapping to `mapping="css/**"`. Which ever you choose, they just need to match each other.

Once they match Spring can then resolve your urls to what they need to be.

Also, just a suggestion for readability. Specify all your `spring:url` elements at the top with a `var` argument and then you can reference that with standard SpEl.

And example is:

```
<spring:url value='/css/style.css' var='styleCss'/>
```

So, that tells Spring that the `styleCss` variable references the resolved url from `/css/style.css`. You can then reference that variable like:

```
<link href="${styleCss}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Obviously, up to you, but I have always found it more readable.

For what it is worth, this can also be done with your JS imports if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,as you both told i have tried  with a / before ,but its not yet loaded the file as i replied to vipin thats what i am getting when i opened that link from page source.Is there anything else to configure like web accessiblity or permission ???

Comment: You shouldn't need too unless you are using Spring security. The issue that you are having appears to be Spring is not resolving your URL and instead is HTML encoding it. You may also need to add a trailing / to your location. So location="/resources/css/". Other than that, if you are using convention based configuration everything should work. If you are not importing the tag library, you may need to do that. Include <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %> at the top of your web page.

Comment: bro, if value='/css/style.css' and mapping and locations are mapping="/css/**" location="/resources" what will happen at reference ?how the location is adding or replacing at value field?